# MAMP: How to add AMF PHP extension?

Tags: macos, mamp, amf

How can I add a PHP extension called "AMF" to my MAMP setup in Mac OSX?

Thanks in advance :)

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it. Here are the tutorial links that I have followed :)

http://developerkarma.com/blog/andrew-m-riley/quick-and-dirty-pecl-mamp-os-x

Other reference link:

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/setup-memcached-mamp-sandbox-environment

Syntax I used:

```
./pecl i amfext-0.9.2
```

---

The links above worked with the newly compiled amf.so in my extensions folder but the AMFEXT php extension did not appear in the phpinfo.php.

I will try to use this link I just found:
http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10363479&page=3

I will update this answer tomorrow if the phpbuilder link worked.

Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

amfext is long outdated and unstable. Check this extension out - http://neoxic.me/php-amf3/

No problem building and integrating into MAMP!